# Win Forms VB App in Win 10 - focus issues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an app built in VB in Visual Studio 2012 that works absolutely fine on my windows 10 desktop, but as soon as i use it on my windows 10 tablet i see a couple of issues :

1) any forms that were intended to be smaller than full screen are shown fullscreen anyway (almost as if you're not allowed any windows less than full screen) i can live with that if need be, but surely theres a way around it?

2) - the most important one - for some strange reason, i start my app, and when i click on a button let's say it opens form 6. once i finish what i'm doing the code closes the form 6, but the previous form is now hidden and all you see is the desktop. ie it's still running, it just lost its focus and must be selected again. I understand i could set the focus to the underlying form before closing form 6, but here's the problem : it can be one of several different forms calling form 6..... so how do i make the app stay aware of what form called form6 so that when done i can return focus there?

this doesnt seem to be a problem on the desktop so i've never encountered it before. i hope one of you experts has dealt with this before

Comment: You'll have to show some code first and narrow the scope of the problem down because this is much too wide.

Comment: not much code to show. on all of my forms if you click on "add item" it executes Form6.show(). When you click on the ok button on form 6, it executes Me.Close(). And focus is lost

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fyi for anyone encountering this problem, i solved it myself and it didn't require any coding. It was a difference between how vb apps act when the tablet is in "TABLET" mode, and when tablet mode is switched off. So all that needed doing is switching off enhanced tablet mode in the windows 10 settings

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points yet to comment. My guess for #1 is either resolution or DPI differences between the 2 screens, and I don't have experience with the latter.

As for #2 and keeping the form aware of who called it, this is how I do it, which may not be the best solution, of course. ;)

First any form that can have multiple callers has a variable defined like

```
Dim callingForm As New Form
```

I typically create an Initialize routine to handle as much as possible before loading a form and this routine is called with the parent form (Me) as a parameter.

```
Dim frm As New frmClient
frm.Initialize(Me)
frm.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

In Initialize, callingForm is set to the parent

```
Public Sub Initialize(parent As Form)
    callingForm = parent
    'whatever else you need to do to init...
End Sub
```

Then when you exit the form...

```
Private Sub exitForm()
    'whatever other closing stuff you need to do...
    callingForm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

That should get you started.